Value for nested if clauses searching text
I have a formula that evaluates if certain text is in a cell and then supplies a values based on what it finds. It uses nested if clauses. I am searching text, not numbers. Individually the clauses work but when nested only the first clause is correctly identified if it exists but if it is from the nested clauses I get a value error. See below. What is wrong here?
=IF(SEARCH("blue",B11), CONCAT("This blue car is a",B11),IF(SEARCH("red",B11), CONCAT("This red car is a",B11),IF(SEARCH("green",B11), CONCAT("This green car is a",B11)," ")))


The help page for SEARCH() states:

If the value of find_text is not found, the #VALUE! error value is returned.

In your formula, not finding "blue" means the formula starts off like this:
=IF(#VALUE!, CONCAT("This blue car is a",B11), IF(...

Since #VALUE! is neither true nor false, the first IF() function returns an error. You could directly address that by wrapping each SEARCH() inside something to check if it's an error since that's all you really care about. You don't care what the exact result is, just whether or not it found something.
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("blue",B11))), CONCAT("This blue car is a",B11),IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("red",B11))), CONCAT("This red car is a",B11),IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("green",B11))), CONCAT("This green car is a",B11)," ")))


That's pretty clunky, though, and it only gets worse as you add more options. Depending on which version of Excel you have, you may be able to make it much simpler to expand your list of search terms. This looks more complicated at first but it is easier to maintain.
If you are only ever going to have a small number of search terms that do not change and you understand the solution above, it is probably not worth it to use the fancier solution below. Making a formula easier to maintain is only useful if it actually requires maintenance and you understand how to maintain it.
(For what it's worth, I don't know why you're searching for a color in B11 and then concatenating the result with B11, but I left it the same thing in this example. The results look weird because of the sample text I chose.)
=LET(searchTerms,{"blue","red","green"},firstMatch,MATCH(1,IFERROR(SEARCH(searchTerms,A1)^0,0),0),IF(ISERROR(firstMatch)," ",CONCAT("This ",INDEX(searchTerms,firstMatch)," car is a ",A1)))

The LET() function allows you to assign values to variable names and later reference those values by name. The terms are in variable,value format except the last term which is the output of the function.

searchTerms,{"blue","red","green"} defines the variable searchTerms to be an array of values. The exact format with curly brackets is important here. To make a longer list of possible terms you've found, just add them to this list.
firstMatch,MATCH(1,IFERROR(SEARCH(searchTerms,A1)^0,0),0) has several steps but the end result is that it tells you which of those search terms appears first in the text. If more than on appears, only the first will match.

SEARCH(searchTerms,A1) searches for each term in the text and returns an array of values (or possibly errors)
IFERROR(SEARCH(~)^0,0) turns that array into all ones (by raising all the values to the power of zero) or zeroes (by replacing all the errors with a zero)
MATCH(1,IFERROR(~),0) find the first 1 in that array. If they're all zeroes, this will be an error.


IF(ISERROR(firstMatch)," ",CONCAT("This ",INDEX(searchTerms,firstMatch)," car is a ",A1)) first checks if the match returns an error (meaning none of the search terms were found) and returns blank. Otherwise, it looks up which color it was (by pulling that term out of the original array) and concatenates it with the rest of the needed text.



i added the concat b11 since in my actual work item I am adding that value and other values into the cell dependent on the result. this was just 'simpler' example. Thanks!

I like this answer, but one needs to be careful implementing it as a phrase like "I bRED a green dog" would give you the wrong answer.

@gns100 That's a very good point. I considered throwing in COUNTIF + wildcards or some kind of regex and it got significantly more complicated. If OP's data lends itself to this kind of issue, they should watch for this.

I'm late to the game but maybe someone else can make use of the following approach. It also needs the caveat similar to the one by @gns100. Adding a space between the asterisks (*) and the _clr variable in the _wldclr argument might avoid some problems but won't avoid all. A key difference with this approach is that it makes use of the wildcard match mode of the XLOOKUP() function, rather than using the SEARCH() function.
 =IFERROR(LET(_clr, {"blue","red","green"}, _wldclr, "*"&_clr&"*", _newclr, CHOOSECOLS(_clr, XMATCH(1, XLOOKUP( _wldclr, A1,1, ,2))),"This " & _newclr & " car is a " & LOWER(A1)), "No match")

LET() statement arguments
_clr is the original array of target colors.
_wldclr creates an array of target colors concatenated with wildcard characters. The XLOOKUP() search uses the wildcard match mode (match mode argument = 2).
_newclr is the column that matches the color being searched. XLOOKUP() returns a 1 if the color is found and XMATCH() returns the spilled array column number that has a 1 in it.

